# Does ImageResizer .Net free version enforce a no-cache header on all images?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, imageresizer

I've added the ImageResizer.MVC nuget package to my MVC4 solution and it works fantastically.

As we come to optimise for release I've noted that all of our images have a Cache Control header like so:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-cache,private,max-age=86400
Date:Wed, 14 Aug 2013 12:23:42 GMT
ETag:"e8611769095ce1:0"
Last-Modified:Fri, 09 Aug 2013 13:00:23 GMT
```

The Cache-Control header has my settings but they are preceded by no-cache.

As a result all of the images have a request to the server which returns a 304.

If I run the project in the visual studio development server then caching works correctly.

[Image Resizer debug page displays as linked here](https://gist.github.com/pauldambra/6230553) mentioning the `ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache` plugin.

I assumed that plugin meant that ImageResizer didn't do any 'clever' caching not that it would add no-cache to the header.

Does `ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache` mean that a Cache-Control header of 'no-cache' is enforced?

---

EDIT: here's the caching settings in the web.config

```
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
  <profiles>
    <add extension=".gif" location="Any" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
    <add extension=".png" location="Any" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="12:00:30" />
    <add extension=".jpg" location="Any" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
  </profiles>
</caching>
```

and

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlCustom="private" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: How did you manage to get the etag and custom cache-control types by using imageresizer plugin. I am facing difficulty in overriding and customizing headers. Please throw me some pointers or leads if you have some.

Comment: Those caching settings on the question were all I added. There may be an IIS config difference between our setups..?

Comment: I had added jpg file profile to cache in my IIS output caching file. Though its the same can you throw what are the setting you are having on your IIS. I am in an impression that setting up configurations in webconfig file will do the stuff. Isn't it true ?

Comment: The comments on a question are really the place for a discussion of a related issue. If you want to ask a question with the detail of your issue and post a link here I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### NoCache is just a non-disk-caching file server; it doesn't prevent caching headers from being served.

It's typically replaced by DiskCache, which includes both server-side disk caching and support for all HTTP caching headers.
You can also add the free ClientCache plugin to serve expires headers.